# First time login to Apache Airflow asks for username and password, what is the username and password?

Tags: airflow

I've just installed Apache Airflow, and I'm launching the webserver for the first time, and it asks me for username and password, I haven't set any username or password.

Can you let me know what is the default username and password for airflow?

[image]

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There is no default username and password created if you are just using python wheel.

Run the following to create a user:

**For Airflow >=2.0.0**:

```
airflow users  create --role Admin --username admin --email admin --firstname admin --lastname admin --password admin
```

OR

**For Airflow <1.10.14**:

```
airflow create_user -r Admin -u admin -e admin@example.com -f admin -l user -p admin
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Kaxil, it worked perfectly, I was using Airflow 2.0.1.

Comment: I've installed airflow in Ubuntu app in Windows 10.  Where should I run the above commands ?  also where I can look for the version info of airflow ? thanks

Comment: Got it! I'm able to add the user now. I did it in the command line.

Comment: What if you forgot your user and password like I stupidly did? haha

Comment: @EvanZamir Delete and recreate :)

Comment: The Airflow 2.0 command also works for version 1.10.15

Comment: Doesn't work, after I executed this command I get a message saying that my login/password is invalid.

Comment: Airflow 2.3.4 install by pip reports that the admin user already exists. But still cannot login. Even after running `airflow sync-perm` as per one of the other answers. However, after restarting Airflow, I noticed that airflow logs a randomly-generated admin password in the console.

Comment: @DNA That will happen if you run `airflow standalone` command, which will print out the username/password on the terminal where you run it

Answer (score 25):

By default, if you are using the docker-compose example provided by airflow, the user is:

```
user: airflow 
password: airflow
```

If you want to create another account with docker use this (you have to be in the same folder of the docker-compose.yaml file):

```
docker-compose run airflow-worker airflow users create --role Admin --username admin --email admin --firstname admin --lastname admin --password admin
```

#### Where to get the Dockerfile?

The example is provided by airflow at [this link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml)

How to build it:

- download the file and saved it with the name `docker-compose.yaml`
- run the command `docker-compose build .` This will create the container needed for running airflow
- run the command `docker-compose up` to start the application
- Using this example, the default user is already created by the airflow-init container. If u want to create another user, use the command above

Comment: doesn't work, there's an error message ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml, compose.yml, compose.yaml

Comment: Are you in the same folder as the yaml file? If not, before running the command, move in that folder

Comment: What yaml file? You didn't even explain what yaml file and where to get it from.

Comment: Well since the question was about how to log in, it supposes that u already have the app up and running. Btw I just updated the description above

Answer (score 19):

After installing Airflow 2.3.4 via `pip`, and running `airflow standalone`, none of the existing answers worked for me (excluding the docker ones, which I did not try) - I could not login with admin:admin.

Running `airflow users create ...` reported that the admin user already existed.

(Also need to be sure to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` otherwise the `users create` command failed due to picking up an old version of sqllite).

Running `airflow sync-perm` made no apparent difference.

After restarting Airflow I noticed that a randomly-generated admin password is logged in the server console, and this logged me in correctly:

```
standalone | Airflow is ready
standalone | Login with username: admin  password: 9fghj2bghT06GBhS
```

This password is also written to `$AIRFLOW_HOME/standalone_admin_password.txt` (but this is not updated if you later change the password manually via the web UI)

Comment: I haven't change the pw but when I get pw on that file , still cannot sign in

Answer (score 7):

I installed AF from hub.docker.com and ran it

```
docker run -dit --name af --rm -p 8080:8080 apache/airflow standalone
```

In this case defaul user is "admin" but password shows nowhere and stores in 'standalone_admin_password.txt'. To see the password run:

```
docker exec af cat standalone_admin_password.txt
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked out of all answers, thank you

Answer (score 3):

I installed version 2.4.2 with pip install, using the Quick Start instructions at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start.html. After starting the server with "airflow standalone" I can login with username "admin" and the password in ~AIRFLOW_HOME/standalone_admin_password.txt

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.3.2:

For anyone getting into `Your user has no roles and/or permissions!` after creating user with following command :

```bash
airflow users create \
    --username admin \
    --firstname Peter \
    --lastname Parker \
    --role Admin \
    --email spiderman@superhero.org
```

You need to sync-perm manually with `airflow sync-perm`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the airflow standalone command then you will get the user and password in the terminal itself:

[image]